# From local server to live web server, links not working [Magento]

Tags: magento, permissions

I've followed [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/27272/#t89572) steps to upload my local magento install my live web server.

Now, the homepage is working fine but every link on it directs you to a 404 not found error. Can't even access "/admin".

I assume this is a problem with the base URL but I've double checked on the database and they're correctly set at "path: web/unsecure/base_url" "value: http://www.mysite.com/"

Anyone got any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you copied the .htaccess file to your server where the rewrite rules are? If .htaccess and mod_rewrite rules are disabled then you can access your admin page via index.php/admin/

Comment: Which .htaccess should I copy and where to put it in a Debian Linux running apache2? Sorry this must be a stupid question.

Edit: Nevermind. I just copied the .htaccess on the root folder of the website to the root folder of the website in the folder and it's working now. Guess it was that .htacess. Thank you!

The /admin still isnt working but I suspect it's another problem.

Comment: just use the one that is bundled with magento installation file

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have Magento set to use Search Engine Friendly URL's - for example, if you go to http://www.medicalexpress.eu/index.php/quem_somos you will see the page..

This can be caused by:

1. Missing .htaccess file in the root of the server
2. mod_rewrite not enabled on the server.

While you are investigating which of the above is the problem you can get the site working again in Magento by going to the System > Configuration > Web in the admin area (http://www.medicalexpress.eu/index.php/admin and then setting "Use Web Server Rewrites" to No under "Search Engines Optimization"

Cheers
Adam