# magento: the requested URL MAGENTO/FURNITURE was not found on this server

Tags: magento, installation

I just installed magento 1.7 using WAMP first. the home page (CMS) works fine after installation. When I click one of the links like FURNITURE or ELECTRONIC or APPAREL or any other link,I get the error "the requested URL MAGENTO/FURNITURE was not found on this server".
I have uninstalled WAMP and tried with Zend sever too. The same problem. 
The PHPMYADMIN had also problem importing the magento sample data in both WAMP and ZENDSERVER installation. I had to import using the mysql command 
     SOURCE c:\magento-sample-data-1.6.1.0;
I have installed magento before many times. So I know how to install.
I checked apache's access.log and error.log. Nothing is registered there.
anyone can help?

Comment: Try rebuilding your catalog url index and flushing all caches.

Comment: how do you rebuild the catalog url index?

Comment: In Admin System > Index Management

Comment: I have already re-indexed all data already and cleared all caches. I do always after new installation.

Comment: Is AllowOverrides All set in your vhost?

Comment: Thanks Roscius. Now it works! the AllowOverrides in Apache line 213 was set None. I changed it to ALL. Now it works. Also disabling the mod_rewrite in admin(system/configuration/web) can make it work too. This two links have likewise answers, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436416/mod-rewrite-zend-server  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150260/from-local-server-to-live-web-server-links-not-working-magento

Answer (score 2):

Moving answer to answer:

Now it works! the AllowOverrides in Apache line 213 was set None. I changed it to ALL. Now it works. Also disabling the mod_rewrite in admin(system/configuration/web) can make it work too. This two links have likewise answers:

[mod_rewrite Zend Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436416/mod-rewrite-zend-server)

[From local server to live web server, links not working [Magento]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150260/from-local-server-to-live-web-server-links-not-working-magento)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem when I first installed Magento using WAMP. This link [From local server to live web server, links not working [Magento]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150260/from-local-server-to-live-web-server-links-not-working-magento) which Roscius provided was helpful.

My problem was resolved when I changed the setting in System > Configuration > Web > Search Engine Optimization > "Use Web server Rewrites" = No